Pass parameters to the script block when using PowerShell module "RunAsUser"
I am writing a PowerShell script to be used in a component in Datto RMM.
To run as the logged in user I am using the PowerShell module RunAsUser.
I would like to be able to pass variables in from the Datto job to a command inside the script block. Here is my code
$scriptblock = {
    param($Message, $WaitSeconds, $Title, $BoxType)

    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $Output =  $wshell.Popup($Message, $WaitSeconds, $Title, $BoxType)
 
    # Due to scope, none of the variables in the scriptblock
    # can be seen outside the block so we need to
    # provide an ouput to the calling object if it wants it.
    Write-Host $Output
}

# see https://github.com/KelvinTegelaar/RunAsUser for specifics
# of invoke-ascurrentuser
$str = invoke-ascurrentuser -scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $env:Message, $env:WaitSeconds, $env:Title, $env:BoxType -CaptureOutput

I don't get an error but I also don't get a message box.
Some ways of doing it I have tried get me no error but a minimal message box as if the parameters were all blank.

@jdweng:  There is no syntax problem with -ArgumentList, so linking elsewhere on that topic (to an unrelated post, no less) is a confusing distraction. Rather, the problem is that the target cmdlet doesn't have an -ArgumentList parameter.


Invoke-AsCurrentUser, part of the RunAsUser module, as of v2.4.0 doesn't support argument-passing, and therefore has no -ArgumentList parameter.
Instead, you must "bake into" the script block any values from the caller's scope you want the script block to operate on:
# Create the script block from an expandable string that references
# variables from the caller's scope and expands them up front.
# Note: This assumes that the environment variables referenced below
#       (e.g. $env:Message) exist and have appropriate values.
$scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create(@"
    # Note: NO param(...) declaration.

    # Note the need to `-escape those $ chars. that shouldn't be
    # expanded up front.
    `$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    
    # Reference the environment variables here, using appropriate
    # embedded quoting:
    `$wshell.Popup("$env:Message", $env:WaitSeconds, "$env:Title", $env:BoxType)

    # Note: No need for an explicit output command:
    #       The .Popup() call's return value is *implicitly* output.
"@)

$str = Invoke-AsCurrentUser -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -CaptureOutput

Note:

The above uses the here-string variant of an expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string ("...") to create the source code for the script block with the caller's values embedded.

The source code is then converted to a script block with [scriptblock]::Create().

An upcoming version of the RunAsUser module will have built-in support for this, via a newly introduced -ExpandStringVariables switch (source code), which allows you to pass regular script-block literals ({ ... }).

Caveat:  You'll still need to manually `-escape $ characters in front of variable references that you do not want expanded (interpolated up front), such as in the case of $wshell above, and you'll still need to use embedded quoting around variable references that may expand to values with spaces or other metacharacters, such as around $env:Message above.




Thank you. that seems a fairly easy solution.

Glad to hear it, @TonyWilliams; my pleasure.

This isn't exactly easier but you can combine ProcessEx Module with a NamedPipeConnectionInfo, this allows you to pass-in parameters very easily even for complex objects, i.e.:
$anObject = @{
    A = @{
        Complex = @{
            Object = 'Hi'
        }
    }
}

$result = Invoke-AsCurrentUserEx {
    param($theObject)

    $theObject['A']['Complex']['Object']
} -ArgumentList $anObject

$result.Success # `Hi`

Your code would translate to this assuming you have installed the Module, first you can define a function that you can re-use later on (you can add this one in your $profile for example):
function Invoke-AsCurrentUserEx {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ArgList')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ArgList')]
        [object[]] $ArgumentList,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Params')]
        [hashtable] $Parameters,

        [ValidateSet('pwsh', 'powershell')]
        [string] $Shell = 'powershell'
    )

    try {
        $id = (Get-Process -Id $pid).SessionId
        $explorer = Get-Process -Name explorer | Where-Object SessionId -EQ $id
        $si = New-StartupInfo -ParentProcess $explorer -WindowStyle Hide
        # start a de-elevated process
        # here you can use `pwsh` instead of `powershell` depending on what shell you wanna use
        $proc = Start-ProcessEx $Shell -StartupInfo $si -CreationFlags NewConsole -PassThru
        # create a new named pipe
        $pipe = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($proc.Id)
        $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($pipe)
        $rs.Open()

        $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
        $ps.Runspace = $rs

        if ($ArgumentList) {
            $ArgumentList | ForEach-Object { $ps = $ps.AddArgument($_) }
        }

        if ($Parameters) {
            $ps = $ps.AddParameters($Parameters)
        }

        $stdout = $ps.Invoke()
    }
    catch {
        $ps.Streams.Error.Add($_)
    }
    finally {
        $ps.Streams.PSObject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('Success', $stdout))

        # dispose resources
        $rs.Dispose()
        $proc | Stop-Process
    }

    $ps.Streams
}

Then the usage is quite straight forward:
Invoke-AsCurrentUserEx {
    param($Message, $WaitSeconds, $Title, $BoxType)

    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $Output = $wshell.Popup($Message, $WaitSeconds, $Title, $BoxType)
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wshell)
    Write-Host $Output
} -ArgumentList 'Hi world', 15, 'Hi world Title', 0


@mklement0 excellent module, like all Jordan's modules

Another take on my previous answer that also uses ProcessEx Module, this version allows to create a de-elevated PSSession that, you can later on, use with Invoke-Command. The downside of this answer is that PSSession.Create wasn't public in older PowerShell versions, in other words, this answer is only compatible with PowerShell 7.3+.
function New-PSSessionEx {
    param(
        [ValidateSet('pwsh', 'powershell')]
        [string] $Shell = 'powershell'
    )

    $id = (Get-Process -Id $pid).SessionId
    $explorer = Get-Process -Name explorer | Where-Object SessionId -EQ $id
    $si = New-StartupInfo -ParentProcess $explorer -WindowStyle Hide
    $proc = Start-ProcessEx $Shell -StartupInfo $si -CreationFlags NewConsole -PassThru
    $pipe = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($proc.Id)
    $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($pipe)
    $rs.Open()
    $registerObjectEventSplat = @{
        InputObject = $rs
        EventName   = 'StateChanged'
        MessageData = $proc.Id
        Action      = {
            if ($EventArgs.RunspaceStateInfo.State -in @('Broken', 'Closed')) {
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $EventSubscriber.SourceIdentifier
                Stop-Process -Id $Event.MessageData -Force
            }
        }
    }
    $null = Register-ObjectEvent @registerObjectEventSplat
    [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession]::Create(
        $rs, [guid]::NewGuid(), $null)
}

Then you can use it with Invoke-Command:
$session = New-PSSessionEx
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { 'hi, i run de-elevated' }
$session | Remove-PSSession

